# How to pass a value from a page to another page in PHP

Tags: php

Im trying to pass a variable value from a page to another page. Im using to go to the next page and I use Session to get the value,

the **link** variable does working but the **price** variable doesn't work

Here's the code:
index.php

```
<?php 

  require('connect.php');
  if(!isset($_SESSION)){
    session_start();
  }

 $query  = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT link, price FROM funnyture WHERE category ='Bed' or category = 'Chairs' or category = 'Tables'") or die("Couldn't find search");
    $count = mysqli_num_rows($query);

    if($count == 0) {
      $output = "There was no row in array";

    } else {

      while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
        $link = $row['link'];
        $price = $row['price'];

        echo '

        <form action="Orderform.php" method="post" class="formClass">

          <input name="link" type="image" src="'.$link.'" value="'.$link.'" class="inputClass">
        </form>';
      }
    }   
?>
```

Orderform.php

```
<?php include 'navbar2.php' ;?>

    <div class="left">
      <?php
      $_SESSION['link'] = $_POST['link'];
       // $_SESSION['price'] = $_POST['price'];
       echo '<img src="'.$_SESSION['link'] .'">';  
       echo '<p>'.$_GET['price'].'</p>';

      ?>
```

Help me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only values that are sent by a form will be in the `GET` or `POST` array.

From what you are showing I conclude that you don't want to show the field in your form, so make it hidden.

Add this inside your form tag:

```
<input name="price" type="hidden" value="'.$price.'" class="inputClass">
```

Also, if you are going to use these values to access the database, be more careful with just taking in variables like this, assume that all user input is wrong and/or dangerous.
You would want to look at things like [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) and [mysqli_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-escape-string.php)

Answer (score 0):

You are fetching the price using **get** method and you have not passed it in your **redirect url**. If you want to fetch that variable on other page using get method then pass it in action url as :

```
<form action="Orderform.php?price=<?php echo $price; ?>" method="post" class="formClass">
```

and fetch as :

```
$price =  $_GET['price'];
```

Or otherwise pass it using a hidden field inside form and fetch using post method.

```
<input name="price" type="hidden"  value="'.$price.'" class="inputClass">
```

and fetch like:

```
$price = $_POST['price'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Data can be Send in multiple ways

1. GET or POST
2. Using Session
3. Using cookie

in your orderform.php you are forgot to start session.